# How to choose a method overload when converting from a QVariant argument?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem.
In my *.cpp I have the following function:

```
void QcWMenuBar::setItems( const QVariantList & items )
{
  clear();
  Q_FOREACH( const QVariant & item, items )
    //addMenu( item );
}
```

Qt has got many different addMenu() functions and therefore my program doesn't know what function to use for a QVariant type.
I would need in this case an `addMenu(QMenu * item)`.

How do I tell Qt to use this function?

Comment: _"Qt has got many different addMenu() functions"_ - and even more `addAction` functions. That's because there many possible scenarios and use cases. Please describe your requirements, what are those `items` (texts, numbers, icons, etc.), what you need to do later when an menu item will be trigered...

Comment: I am helping out to develop the audio programming language SuperCollider.

Comment: Sorry, it will take me long time to find corelation between what I asked and what you answered...

Comment: Sorry.. I just pressed "Enter" too early. :) Technically, through an outer language (SuperCollider) I create a function which triggers the creation of a QMenu and QMenuBar. The problem is that (I guess), when I compile the application with CMake the software *does not know* what type of input it has to expect (as there is a general QVariant). How can I tell the application what "type" to expect out of a QVariantList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to obtain the value of the right type from the variant:

```
void QcWMenuBar::setItems(const QVariantList & items)
{
  clear();
  for (auto & item: items) {
    Q_ASSERT(item.canConvert<QMenu*>());
    addMenu(item.value<QMenu*>());
  }
}
```